# Getting error while packaging the code for ipad device using flashbuilder

Tags: flash-builder, flex4.5, flex-mobile

This is vengatesh. I am developing mobile application for android devices and apple ipad, using flashbuilder 4.5 premium.After the completion of code , I can easily create apk file for android devices but I couldn't be able to create ipa file for APPLE devices.While packaging , I got some java exception error like

"Exception in threa "main" java.lang.NullPointerException"

[image]

Please guide me on this issue . I am in urgency to complete my project for ipad devices

i used the my indexedarray as

```
  for( var j:int = 0; j<controlsXML.length(); j++)
            {

                if(sectionXML[i].@Name == controlsXML[j].@SectionName)
                {

                    indexedArray.push({controlName:controlsXML[j].@Name,Horder:controlsXML[j].@HOrder,Vorder:controlsXML[j].@VOrder});

                }

            }

            indexedArray.sortOn(["Horder","Vorder"],[Array.NUMERIC,Array.NUMERIC]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these links will helpful for you:

http://va.lent.in/blog/2011/03/25/air2-6-app-for-ios/
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/packaging-air-apps-android.html
http://tv.adobe.com/.../build-your-first-mobile-application-in-flash-builder-45/
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/iphone/WS789ea67d3e73a8b2-48bca492124b39ac5e2-7ffb.html
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f2fea1812938a6e463-8000.html 
http://www.riagora.com/2010/12/tips-for-flex-mobile-apps/ 
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/mobile_development_hero_burrito.html 
http://tv.adobe.com/watch/adc-presents/flex-mobile-part-2-navigation-and-lists/
http://www.yeahbutisitflash.com/?p=986
http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-use-Adobes-iPhone-Packager-without-an-Appl/

Are you following all the steps of packaging correctly?

Comment: dear swati, i have followed the steps given in the links which you provide.but still i am having the java exception error which packaging for ios.

Comment: can you provide the exact error which is displaying in your output window? may be that would be useful for me for finding your problem more specifically.

Comment: thanks, It looks like a problem with your array you are using in your custom classes Algorithms and GlobalOptimizer. Please make sure array in these classes are properly initialized or not. but i am sure this error occur bcoz array indexs are not filled sequentially.

Comment: swati, i used only one indexed array in my code and all others are of type XMLlistcollections.my indexedarrays are filled correctly.but still i am getting de same error.